# Using ASP.NET MVC 2 with Sharepoint Publishing

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-mvc-2

I need include asp mvc project in sharepoint, found this guide http://aspalliance.com/1944_Using_ASPNET_MVC_2_with_Sharepoint_Publishing.all but when i try go on  http://samplemvc get error - Unable to load file or assembly  "SampleMVC". MVC and Sharepoint in same application pool. Maybe somebody know how solved this problem or know another way to use it together.
I know about SharepointMvc, but he not suitable.
I use windows 7, sharepoint 2010, iis 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get that error, it typically means that it's looking for SampleMVC.dll, but it can't find it in either the GAC or the bin directory on the IIS site.  Did you deploy SampleMVC.dll?

From the link you provided, SampleMVC.dll is the assembly that contains your definition for the CustomHttpApplication class.

Comment: if create virtual directory with project in same pool then search this dll  will be  in virtual folder too or I wrong?
Try insert dll in bin directory and I got same error.

Comment: Strange but copied dll in GAC and this error disappeared. Thanks for the help!